# Regex - Ignore part of the string

Tags: java, regex, pentaho

I am working on Pentaho which uses Java regex package : java.util.regex.

I want to extract a lot of information from the lines of a text file from both start and end of the string :

```
^StartofString Controls\(param1="(D[0-9]{0,})",param2="(G[0-9]{0,})",param3="([^"]{0,})",param4="([^"]{0,})"\):(?:.*)param5="([^"]{0,})",.*
```

There is a long part of the string I want to ignore and try to do so with `(?:.*)`

The positive lookahead seems working when I test the Regex on the step but does not work when I execute the transformation.
I test the string on 'Regex Evaluation' step, check with 'Filter rows' the boolean of previous step and extract groups within a Javascript step :

```
var pattern = Packages.java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(patternStr);
var matcher = pattern.matcher(content.toString());
var matchFound = matcher.find();
```

with patterStr being the same regex than the one in the 'Regex Evaluation' step but with escaping characters : \

I have read many questions about ignoring parts of strings in regex and still can't find the answer.
Any help is welcome.
I can provide more informations if needed.

Comment: No idea what your issue is. One thing is certain: `(?:.*)` is a non-capturing group and not a lookahead.

Comment: Can we see the transformation code? Using a non-capturing group by itself won't do the trick : non-capturing group means there is no capturing group, but the matched text is still present in the output ; just not in a group

Comment: ... I mixed up non-capturing group and lookahead. What I want is to not capture the big part of the string until I reach param5.
Not sure how seeing the full transformation would help, and there is sensible information I should not show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non capturing group doesn't mean that its content won't be captured, it means that it won't be captured in a group (although you're still grouping tokens in your regex, which can be useful to apply a modifier to them at once).

For example, these regex will all match the exact same `abc` string :

```
abc
a(?:b)c
a(b)c
```

However in the third case, you've defined a capturing group which will enable you to access to `b` independently. The first two cases are equals in all respects.

The non-capturing group becomes useful when you want to apply a modifier to a group of tokens without having an extra group you can reference later. The following regexs will all match the same strings :

```
(ab)*(c)\2
(?:ab)*(c)\1
```

We want to apply `*` to the `ab` tokens. Either we do it with a capturing group (first example) and a group is created that we can reference, or we use a non-capturing group. The backreference at the end of the regex is supposed to match the `c` ; in the first example it's the second group since `ab` is the first one, while in the second `c` is the first group that can be referenced.

Now that I've explained what non-capturing groups do, let's solve your problem : you want to remove something from the middle of your string, where you know what's at the beginning and what's at the end.

Let's assume the string you want to match is the following :

```
Aremove-thisB
```

And that you want the result `AB`.

There are multiple strategies to do so, the easiest in your case probably is to match both the beginning and end of the string in their own capturing group and create your output from there :

```
var pattern = Packages.java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(A).*(B)");
var matcher = pattern.matcher(content.toString());
var matchFound = matcher.find();
if (matchFound) { return matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2); }
```

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer but it still does not fully answers my question.
The string I want to match looks more like 
`A=text1,remove-this,B=text2`
And I want to capture separately text1 and text2

Comment: @v01dv01d use capturing groups in order to be able to reference `text1` and `text2` independently : match `A=([^,]*).*B=([^,]*)` for example, then your matcher's `.group(1)` will contain `text1` and `.group(2)` `text2`. `[^,]*` will match everything up to the next comma excluded

Comment: I got the logic and tried but still does not work.
Well, this is so far how looks the regex :
`^GetAndUpdate pcParamQualite\(sDomaineApplicatif="(D[0-9]{0,})",sApplication="(G[0-9]{0,})",sFonctionnalite="([^"]{0,})",sNumeroOrdre="([^"]{0,})"\):.*sCodeMsgExpliControle="([^"]{0,})",.*`
The thing I want to ignore is between the colon and sCodeMsgExpliControle (and there is more after that, I just cut it for example)

Comment: Looks good to me, what's your current problem? You should be able to retrieve the domaineApplicatif in the first group, the application in the second, the fonctionnalite in the third, the numeroOrder in the fourth and the codeMsgExpliControle in the fifth. I'd replace the `{0,}` by `*`, but that shouldn't change anything. Also you probably don't need to match the rest of the string (your trailing `.*`)

Comment: Row level logging on Pentaho shows that the lines read are cut (or are they only for esthetics ?), thus being bad as sCo‌​deMsgExpliControle is not even reached. Only solution would be to cut lines by another step...

Comment: I don't know Pentaho at all, I won't be able to help you on that. You could test your regex on a site like https://regex101.com in order to make sure it's correct (don't forget that doubling the `\ ` if you have some is specific to Java, don't double them on regex101 ; aside from that the PHP(PCRE) regex style will behave the same as the java.util.regex package)

Comment: It does work on regex101, I always test there before building a transformation in Pentaho.
But thank you for your help and the time spent for me.
Have a nice day.